# Suggestions on how this .bashrc backup script can be improved?

Tags: bash, scripts, alias

```
alias isbashrcmodf='cmp -s "/home/user/.experimental/bc/$(ls /home/user/.experimental/bc -Art | tail -n 1)" "/home/user/.bashrc"'
alias bashrcbak='cp ~/.bashrc ~/.experimental/bc/.bashrc$(date +-%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s)'
if isbashrcmodf; then
    cd $PWD
else
    bashrcbak; echo ".bashrc backed, good to go."
fi
```

The above script checks the folder `/home/user/.expiremental/bc/` for the last modified file (which is previous backup of my `.bashrc`) and if the present `.bashrc` is different, a backup is made

I possibly want to avoid the `if .. then` part and only have `if .. else` segment. The `cd $PWD` is a hack way of doing nothing which I used since I couldn't find any better *doing nothing command*.

**EDIT** :

I just read somewhere a detailed article on how dangerous it is to parse `ls` output and rely on `ls`, it went on saying that it is safer to use **glob** along `ls` so instead of `ls /home/user/.experimental/bc -Art | tail -n 1` it should be :
`ls /home/user/.experimental/bc/.bashrc-* -Art | tail -n 1`

Comment: "if .. then part and only have if .. else segment." what do you mean by that? Cuz that's how bash does if constructs.

Comment: @Rinzwind I actually tried using `if .. then` with `!$isbashrcmodf` didn't work so any better bash construct you know of that could be used ? Give me examples too, I'm a very slow and dumb learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional 'OR' operator `||` and group your dependent commands inside curly braces so they're executed together, though each command must have a trailing `;`:

```
alias isbashrcmodf='cmp -s "/home/user/experimental/bc/$(ls /home/user/experimental/bc -Art | tail -n 1)" "/home/user/.bashrc"'
alias bashrcbak='cp ~/.bashrc ~/.experimental/bc/.bashrc$(date +-%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s)'

isbashrcmodf || { bashrcbak ; echo ".bashrc backed, good to go."; }
```

A further improvement may be to use the 'AND' conditional operator `&&` to only echo if the bashrcbak command is successful:

```
isbashrcmodf || { bashrcbak && echo ".bashrc backed, good to go."; }
```

Comment: I don't know what `cd $PWD` did in OP's script, but it doesn't appear in yours.

Comment: @dessert `cd $PWD` was my hack way of _doing nothing_ in the `then` part of script since I'm too lazy to search about and `learn if .. then .. else`.

Comment: @Arronical Is using `$(ls /home/user/experimental/bc -Art | tail -n 1)` safe for getting last modified file _or_ can that be improved too ?

Comment: @Hannibal :D I like that approach!

Comment: @Hannibal Next time you need a shell command that does nothing at all, I recommend using the `:` builtin, which exists for that purpose. For details, run `help :` in `bash`, or check out [`:`'s its documentation in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16_01). See also [What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the NOT operator `!` when you want to reverse an `if` statement.

   ```
   if ! isbashrcmodf; then
   ```
2. Use the AND operator `&&` when you want to run a command only if the last command succeeded.

   ```
   bashrcbak && echo ".bashrc backed up, good to go."
   ```
3. Don't bother reversing `ls` sort.

   ```
   ls ... -At | head -1
   ```
4. Specify which files `ls` should look at, with a glob.

   ```
   ~/.experimental/bc/.bashrc-*
   ```
5. Use tildes and vars.

   ```
   dir=~/.experimental/bc
   bak_prev="$dir/$(ls "$dir"/.bashrc-* -At | head -1)"
   cmp -s "$bak_prev" ~/.bashrc
   ```

   and

   ```
   bak_next="$dir/.bashrc-$(date +%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s)"
   cp ~/.bashrc "$bak_next"
   ```

   This is partly a matter of personal taste, but it also makes it so that if you want to change the backup dir (for example), you only have to modify one line of code, where `$dir` is set.
6. Don't use aliases when you should use functions. Aliases are meant to be used only in interactive sessions, mostly for commands you often run with a certain set of arguments. E.g. `alias ls='ls --color=yes'`.

   ```
   isbashrcmodf(){
       local bak_prev="$dir/$(ls "$dir"/.bashrc-* -At | head -1)"
       cmp -s "$bak_prev" ~/.bashrc
   }

   bashrcbak(){
       local bak_next="$dir/.bashrc-$(date +%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s)"
       cp ~/.bashrc "$bak_next"
   }
   ```

   Although in this case, the functions/aliases are only used once, so I wouldn't even bother, unless there is more to the script you didn't include.
7. Pay very close attention to filenames.

   `experimental` (typo in the script)

   `.expiremental` (typo in the question)

In full:

```
dir=~/.experimental/bc
bak_prev="$dir/$(ls "$dir"/.bashrc-* -At | head -1)"
if ! cmp -s "$bak_prev" ~/.bashrc; then
    bak_next="$dir/.bashrc-$(date +%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s)"
    cp ~/.bashrc "$bak_next" &&
        echo ".bashrc backed up, good to go."
fi
```

Comment: I corrected the typo, thanks for pointing out, and +1 for telling me using `function` is better than using `alias`.

Comment: I'm replacing my aliases with function, can you point out why they are better ?

Comment: @Hannibal In this case, mostly because it's a good habit. Aliases are very inflexible compared to functions. If you wanted to do anything more complex than this (like handling arguments/options), you would need to use functions anyway.

Comment: @Hannibal For more details, see [alias vs. function in bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/q/163882/301745) and [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/117037).

Comment: read both of the Qs but answers are imho expansion of your 2nd comment, so I thought of asking you I could : `alias dodis='cp /blah/blah2/x  /blah/blah2/x.bak; echo "didit"'` _or_ `dodis() { cp /blah/blah2/x  /blah/blah2/x.bak; echo "didit" }` which of these is faster ?

Comment: @Hannibal They should be about as fast, but you should use the function, especially where the code contains  two commands. Btw, using `cp -v` may be better than echoing a confirmation.

Comment: yup using `function`'s