# How to write alias when the command includes file path

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a command like
python abc.py -p 'File Path' -c 'File path'.

Comment: Are all the parts of the `python abc.py -p 'File Path' -c 'File path'` always the same?

Comment: Only 'File Path' varies , rest is same .

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you wanted to ask is how to use command line arguments in conjunction with an *alias* (which you cannot).
Try to define a *function* instead:

- Using [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh):

  ```
  % func abc() { echo python abc.py -p "$1" -c "$2" }
  % abc def ghi
  python abc.py -p def -c ghi
  ```
- Using [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)):

  ```
  $ function abc { echo python abc.py -p "$1" -c "$2"; }
  $ abc def ghi
  python abc.py -p def -c ghi
  ```

  You might also want to have a look at [alias vs. function in bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/q/163882/525098).

Comment: Very good suggestion, but is this valid bash code? Can the new user understand this example for solving the question?

Comment: @vanadium OP didn't mention which shell s/he uses (and the provided reference should explain further details), but fair enough; I added a Bash-conformant example.

Comment: Excellent. Bash is the default in the Ubuntu desktop, but it is excellent, of course, also to show how it works for other shells.

Comment: ... or portably, `abc () { echo python abc.py -p "$1" -c "$2"; }`